# What is causing pathauto to generate unwanted text in these URLs?

Tags: path-aliases

I have configured `pathauto` to generate URLs for content according to this pattern `article/[node:author]/[current-page:title]-[node:nid]`. `article` is a literal input, to reflect the content type description `Site Article` not token generated.

The content type description is `Site Article`

The node title is: `this is a title`

The author's name is: `nodecreator`

The node id is: `101`

When I generate the URL alias using the pattern `article/[nodecreator]/[current-page:title]-[node:nid]`, the resulting path 's `article/nodecreator/edit-site-article-this-is-a-title-101`. The last section on the URL shouldn't be prefixed by `edit-site-article`.

What could be the cause?

Comment: I would look into node:title instead of current-page:title as I bet what's going on is this is being saved when you are actually editing the node, eg, sitting on node/###/edit and drupal is actually grabbing the title then, eg, when it is actually called edit something or other, and then it is then being saved and being used all the time, eg, when just viewing the node.

Comment: You are right. You might as well turn your comment into a proper answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pathauto creates the alias when a node is being added or edited, so, if you are using `current-page:title` it will include the title that Drupal generates for that page, eg, in your case, "Edit Site Article: This is a title", and not just the title of the node.  So I would look into using `node:title` instead so as to remove any of those potential prefixings.